# Sequelize join and relationships

Tags: node.js, database, join, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have a database running, but I've not been able to execute a join between two tables. I already did a join between two other tables but this one doesn't work.

On my db.js file I establish the following relationship between tables:

```
db.diet.hasMany(db.meal, {as : 'Diet', foreignKey : 'dietId'});
```

And on my server.js file, I'm trying to build this query:

```
db.meal.findAll({
    include : [db.diet],
    where : {
        dietId : idDiet
    }
}).then(function (meals) {
    res.json(meals)
});
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: idDiet is not defined
```

I also tried querying the diet table like this:

```
db.diet.findAll({
    include :[db.meal],
    where : {
        idDiet : dietId
    }
}).then(function (meals) {
    res.json(meals);
});
```

But it also gives me an error:

```
ReferenceError: dietId is not defined
```

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

Thank you so much, any help is appreciated. If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: console.log `diedId` to see what you get

Comment: I dont think I can do that, as I can't even join the tables before getting the error

Comment: Aah right I see what you're trying to be doing. You're joining the `meal` and `diet` together. You're trying to query the `meal` with all its `diet` attached right?

Comment: Yes, my SQL would be something like this: 
SELECT * FROM diets join meals on idDiet = dietId;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
db.diet.hasMany(db.meal, {as : 'Diet', foreignKey : 'dietId'});
```

Should be this:

```
db.diet.hasMany(db.meal, {as : 'Meals'});
```

You're saying that `diet` has many `meal` models known as `Meals` so you'll be able to include the `Meals` with the `diet`.

```
db.diet.findAll({
  include: [db.meal] // include the meal in the query ("join")
}).then((diet) => {
  // diet.Meals is a array of "meal" models that
  // belongs to the queried "diet"
});
```

I've answered as similiar question like this over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822966/3254198

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question, my database is already in production, can I change the relationship on my db.js file? Or would that be illegal?