# Sequelize: Creating to-many relationships

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize in Node and have a table name `User` and `Auth`:

```
User 
    id
    name

Auth:
    id
    token
```

I would like to add relationships to this model.

A `User` can have many `Auth`'s, `to-many` relationship with `Auth`.

An `Auth` can only have one `User`, `to-one` relationship with `User`.

I have a class instance in my model file that I am using to create relationships with the following code:

```
tableName: 'User',
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    user.belongsToMany(user, { through: { model: models.auth }, as: `user` })
                }
```

This code creates a field in `Auth`, called `userId`.

What I am hoping to get is the following:

```
 User 
    id
    name
    auths //an array that will contain all instances of Auth by this User

Auth:
    id
    token
    user //an object of User to whom this Auth object belongs to
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    ...
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            User.hasMany(models.Auth, {as: 'auths'});
        }
    }
};


var Auth = sequelize.define('Auth', {
    ...
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            Auth.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'user'});
        }
    }
};
```

This'll add a `userId` column to the `auth` table.

To query it you'd do (note the `include` in the query) you can also do it vice-versa:

```
User.findOne({
    include: [Auth]
})
```

You might want to check the sequelize docs for [one-to-many](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-many-associations), [hasOne](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#hasone) relationships and the [hasMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-many/), [hasOne](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-one/) API for more info.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get back an array of all the `Auth` records associated with one `User`?  Shouldn't the `User` table have a field called `Auths`?

Comment: You just need the reference in one table, not both and in the query you'd tell it to include a second model. I've added a query example as well to my post.